# Holding ConnectionString in app.config or properties.Resources of a C# project?

Tags: c#, app-config, connection-string

I've saved my project connection string in app.config file and use it without any problem.
But some one told me that she has put it in Properties.Resources of her project.

Now, my question is is there any preference between these two ways? or what else do you offer?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It's better to put it in app.Config if you want to be able to change this post-deployment.  If you only need it to be configurable at compile time, either option is fine.  Compile-time only configuration in resources has the advantage of both hiding the configuration string, and potentially making one fewer files to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

This has always been an interesting one to answer. It all depends on your current situation and needs.

1. Will you have to change the
   connection string post deploy?
2. Security considerations -> Someone
   might be able to get access to your
   database from the stored credential.
   (How much permissions does that
   credential have?, etc..)

If you want the flexibility to change connection strings easily post deploy, that maybe app.config might be easiest option.

If security is a concern, then you could look at two things.

1. Locking down permission on that
   credential (only give the minimum
   required rights for you app to work)
2. Encrypting your connection string.
   (Have a look at [MS Enterprise
   Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/), from memory they will store
   the connection string encrypted and
   decrypt for you)
3. Storing connection string in
   registry
4. Encrypting and storing connection
   string in registry (If it is a major concern. It about making it harder for the hacker.)